# Apt problems no installations or uninstallations possible

Tags: apt, software-installation, software-uninstall

This is my first post. Please let me know if I do something wrong. My problem is that I can't install or uninstall anything. Here are the errors:

```
Entfernen von linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic (4.10.0-42.46) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.10.0-42-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.10.0-42-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-42-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.10.0-42-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-42-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-42-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.10.0-42-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-42-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/zz-busybox-initramfs failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-42-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic (--remove):
 Unterprozess installiertes post-removal-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurück
Entfernen von linux-image-extra-4.13.0-37-generic (4.13.0-37.42) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.13.0-37-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.13.0-37-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.13.0-37-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-37-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/zz-busybox-initramfs failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-37-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes linux-image-extra-4.13.0-37-generic (--remove):
 Unterprozess installiertes post-removal-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurück
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.13.0-37-generic
```

I used `apt install -f` and `dpkg --configure -a` This ended with these errors:

```
root@ubu:~# apt install -f
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Die folgenden Pakete werden ENTFERNT:
  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-37-generic
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 2 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
3 nicht vollständig installiert oder entfernt.
Nach dieser Operation werden 321 MB Plattenplatz freigegeben.
Möchten Sie fortfahren? [J/n] j
(Lese Datenbank ... 291052 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Entfernen von linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic (4.10.0-42.46) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.10.0-42-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.10.0-42-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-42-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.10.0-42-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-42-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-42-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.10.0-42-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-42-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/zz-busybox-initramfs failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-42-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic (--remove):
 Unterprozess installiertes post-removal-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurück
Entfernen von linux-image-extra-4.13.0-37-generic (4.13.0-37.42) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.13.0-37-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.13.0-37-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.13.0-37-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-37-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/zz-busybox-initramfs failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-37-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes linux-image-extra-4.13.0-37-generic (--remove):
 Unterprozess installiertes post-removal-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurück
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.13.0-37-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

root@ubu:~# dpkg --configure -a
Trigger für man-db (2.7.6.1-2) werden verarbeitet ...
Trigger für dbus (1.10.22-1ubuntu1) werden verarbeitet ...
```

I have no idea what to do now. Could some one please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try 'sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a' and see what happens.

Comment: I did sudo -s. I was root I guess

Comment: Yes you were, but the command I mentioned is different what you did before :)

Comment: Oops sorry. I'll try sind give a feedback in zur next days.

Comment: -a is not an available option when I use dpkg-reconfigure.

Comment: sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a actually reconfigures all installed packages. See here https://manpages.debian.org/wheezy/debconf/dpkg-reconfigure.8.en.html

Comment: Yeah I thought this too but it sais unknown option as you can see from my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Unknown option: a*

Aufruf: dpkg-reconfigure [Optionen] Pakete

-u,  --unseen-only        Nur noch nicht gestellte Fragen zeigen.

```
   --default-priority   Voreingestellte Priorität benutzen (statt niedrig).

   --force          Neukonfiguration kaputter Pakete erzwingen.

   --no-reload      Vorlagen nicht neu laden. (Vorsichtig verwenden)
```

-f,  --frontend       Zu benutzende Debconf-Oberfläche angeben.

-p,  --priority       Minimale anzuzeigende Priorität für Fragen angeben.
       --terse          Kompakten Modus aktivieren.

Answer (score 1):

But I finally got it. I used dpkg-reconfigure initramfs-tools. Then I found a post where they used dpkg -C. This showed me what the problem was. A part of initramfs at /usr was not found. So I did chmod -x /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/zz-busybox-initramfs and then apt install -f and dpkg-reconfigure initramfs-tools. After that installing was possible.